# DataTable slow when drawing multiple of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a web application that require multiple redraw of DataTable's instances. Each of them has very small datasource but when I do a performance checking of a normal instance

```
var table = $("#Table").DataTable({
    "data": smallData
});
$("#Table").clear():
$("#Table").rows.add(otherSmallData).draw();
```

It already took 200ms. In my case, updating all instances would took 2 seconds(2 seconds browser-freezed). Is there anyway to do it client-side smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`deferRender`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender) option for deferred rendering for additional speed of initialization.

```
var table = $("#Table").DataTable({
   "data": smallData,
   "deferRender": true
});
```

Comment: It does not really increase performance since defer option is supposed for large dataset I think

Answer (score 1):

You're already creating a reference to the table with jQuery, what happens when you use that instead of digging into the DOM? Like this:

```
var table = $("#Table").DataTable({
    "data": smallData
});
table.clear().rows.add(otherSmallData).draw();
```

Comment: I cannot since in the actual function, there is a if-else check. The table will only initialize the first time.